# Issue with excel and Match

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the following in an excel table:

```
A1: Labeling
B1: [L-1.1.2-A] - Not for use in patient environment according to IEC 60601-1 (3rd edition) (in e-manual or printed manual)[L-1.1.2-B] - Hardware is labeled with instructions and warnings to remove power before opening the case in the OEM manuals. (in e-manual or printed manual)
F1: L-1.1.2-A
G1: =INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*"&F1&"*";B:B;0))

A2: Design
B2: [D-1.1.2-A] - Equipment not used in patient environment according to IEC 60601-1 (3rd edition)[D-1.1.2-B] - IEC 60601-1 or IEC60950
F2: D-1.1.2-A
G2: =INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*"&F2&"*";B:B;0))
```

Columns A, B and F are formatted as Text.

My problem is that G1 returns #N/A when clearly the string is found in B1 and it should return "Labeling". On the other hand, G2 correctly returns "Design". If I do a normal search for the string in F1, it is found in cell B1. Any idea what may possibly go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue is that MATCH only works with cells that have a max of 255 characters. As soon as the length is beyond that, it returns an error. To circumvent that, I used the following formula instead:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH("*"&F1&"*";MID(B:B;SEARCH(F1;B:B);20);0))
```

Since it is an array formula, it needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This works also if the string you search for is beyond the 255th character.

Big thanks **@jonno** who pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

As you've identified, there is a character limit of 255 for `MATCH`, which is frustrating.

Looking at your data, it looks like you can fairly safely assume the data will always be in the first 255 characters? If so, you can use the following *array formula*:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&F1&"*",LEFT(B:B,255),0))
```

This will cut the first 255 characters from the left. Remember, as an array formula you must use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (It should show the formula with curly braces around it when correctly entered).

Comment: Hi, I thought of that but there are cases when it isn't in the first 255.

Comment: yes please. Something where the match can be beyond the 255th character